# Primefaces datatable columns too long

Tags: primefaces

I am trying to use a datatable. But at some zoom percentages in the browser, the datatables looks weird. With rows wider than the header.

[image]

How can I make the header the same width as the rows?
This happens only at certain percentages. 
It changes with the percentage.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my bootsrap template. 
This component was inside a col-lg-6 div. 
I removed and now looks really good.

Regards,
Daniel